# How to render the Json string from a variable into form.io

Tags: angular

I am working in https://www.form.io/opensource with angular 7 project. 
Here i can save the designed form as a JSON string into sql server database. after that when i try to render the form i fetch the JSON string into a variable using WEB API and i try to assign into  tag it's not working. But when I copy the same string and place in an HTML code it's working.

// I tried like this

`<formio [form]='myForm'></formio>`

//here myForm is a variable. I assign the JSON string into that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the library you're using? https://github.com/formio/angular-formio

You probably need to pass in a JSON *string* not a JSON object. Try this:

**Template.html**

```html
<formio [form]="myFormJsonString"></formio>
```

**Component.ts**

```
myFromJsonString: string;

constructor() {
  this.myFromJsonString = JSON.stringify(myForm);
}
```